# Opening and editing SQLWindows applications

Tags: sql-server, windows, ide, guptateamdeveloper

I have to edit a number of SQL Windows applications that I have inherited. This is not something that i've done before and i'm having trouble finding an IDE or similar (never mind editing the code!) as it seems a number of responsible companies have gone bust in the years since these apps were written, can anybody advise on how I can proceed?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only IDE you can use is the Gupta/Centura Team Developer. Even if the code was saved in text format, you need the TD to compile it.
If you first have to get one: Gupta/Centura was bought by [Unify](http://www.unify.com/Products/TeamDeveloper/default.aspx)

Comment: I eventually found an old cd of SQLWindows Corporate Edition 5.0.4 by Centura Software Corporation which seems to work.

Now the fun begins :)